# error "cannot appear in a constant-expression" in g++ but not in gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

```
 98 static inline int set_hw_br(pid_t tracee, dr7_t *pdr7, void *addr, int dr_index)
 99 {
100     errno = 0;
101     printf("LINE = %d <pid> %d, dr_index= %d addr=%u \n",__LINE__, tracee, dr_index, addr);
102     //if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, tracee, offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[dr_index]), addr))
103     if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, tracee, offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[dr_index]), addr))
104     {
105         int ii = errno;
106         printf("MKH: 22  errno = %d\n", ii);
107         ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, tracee, 0, 0);
108         return -1;
109     }
110     else
111         printf("PTRACE_POKEUSER passed...\n");
```

Above code(part of main code) is successfully compiled in GCC compiler. But while compiling through G++, it is giving fillowing error: `error: 'dr_index' cannot appear in a constant-expression` in line 103. set_hw_br is called from another function.

Any idea why this failing in g++?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the complete code of the function

Comment: It depends on the definition of macro offsetof. Show how it is defined.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, with GCC it is defined as [`__builtin_offsetof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html) so seeing the macro definition won't help.

Comment: It's a broken [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions). The C99 language standard requires `offsetof` to produce a constant expression.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the error isn't saying `offsetof` doesn't _produce_ a constant expression it's saying an input to it is not a constant expression. The C11 standard requires that for `offsetof` `&t.member-designator` is an address constant, and that's obviously not true for `&t.a[nonconstant]`. The GCC C front-end apparently allows non-constant input, and you get non-constant output. The C++ front-end is stricter, which makes sense given the more extensive rules about constant expressions in C++

Comment: @JonathanWakely If my reading of the C99 standard is correct, C requires the input of `offsetof` to be a constant expression as well; GCC's implementation lifts this restriction, but apparently only for C, not for C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `offsetof` macro requires that the *member-designator* has to produce an address constant (C11 7.19/3):

> ```
> offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of
>   which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by *member-designator*),
>   from the beginning of its structure (designated by *type*). The type and member designator
>   shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.`*member-designator*`)` evaluates to an address constant. (If the
>   specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)

In your code, `t.u_subreg[dr_index]` is not a constant, because `dr_index` is not a constant.

GCC implements `offsetof` with a [compiler intrinsic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html) so what is allowed in an `offsetof` expression depends on the rules of GCC's intrinsic.  As an extension to the standard, the GCC C front-end allows a non-constant expression as input and produces a non-constant result. The C++ front-end does not allow it, giving the error telling you `dr_index` cannot be used there.

You can change the `offsetof` expression to only use constants:

```
offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0])
```

then you can add the index to it, where `T` is the type in the array `u_debugreg`:

```
offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0]) + sizeof(T)*dr_index
```

(This assumes that `u_debugreg` is an actual array, not a pointer).

Comment: @Yakk, it works either way (with GCC anyway). I kept it there because it keeps the code  closer to the original: it's obviously getting the offset of the first array element, and so it's easy to get the Nth element from that too.  You are correct that the offset of the array is the same as the offset of the first element, and so both work.